# PCA whitening and centering in inference/test samples

Tags: pca, scikit-learn, centering, latent-dirichlet-alloc

*[cross-posted from SO]*

I'm working on speaker identification. I need to take the speaker embeddings from a neural network and apply a few transformations to finally generate the score for verification.

I get the following data from the neural net,

```
X_embeddings with shape (14290, 512)
y_embeddings with shape (14290,)
```

Here, there are 14290 samples, 512 unit embedding vectors.

Now, I want to apply zero-centering, and PCA whitening on the data, then finally train an LDA model on the data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# centering, unit variance
scaler = StandardScaler() # zero mean (feature-wise), unit-var
scaler.fit(X_enrollment)

X_enrollment = scaler.transform(X_enrollment)

# whitening
pca = PCA(whiten = True) # X_enrollment already unit variance
pca.fit(X_enrollment)
X_enrollment = pca.transform(X_enrollment)
```

Now, the test samples come from a much larger size and randomly. So, I have to process the test samples online.

Should I directly apply the `transform` from the `scaler` and `pca` to the test samples (each with shape `(1, 512)`)? Or, is there a better approach to handle the test pre-processing?

Comment: I don't use scikit-learn so can't comment on your code, but it's important here that you do not compute a new PCA on the test data, but rather project them on the PCs from the training data.

Comment: @ChristianHennig yes, that is what I am currently doing. Thanks for the suggestion.